# Expanding variable at function definition in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm having some trouble with trying to evaluate/expand a variable when I define a function in zsh - Is this possible?
Example:

```
variable=foo
mytest(){
  echo ${variable}  
}
mytest           //outputs foo
variable=bar
test           //outputs bar
```

I want variable inside test() to stay foo and not be affected by $variable anymore. I have been reading the manual and trying eval and different quoting but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need a [local variable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Local-Parameters) so e.g. `f_test(){ local var=value; print -l ${var}; }`

Comment: I still need the variable inside the function to be set from the variable outside the function, just not changed after the function is declared

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You should not use a variable name that you want to reuse later for other things.

Comment: Nope, you'll need a different language. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94129/is-there-something-like-closures-for-zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a variable inside your function which, once set, keeps their value. Since this can be done only with a global variable, you need to give it a different name, for instance:

```
xtest(){
  typeset -g test_variable
  : ${test_variable:=$variable}
  echo $test_variable
}
```

This sets `test_variable` on the first invocation of the function, but doesn't overwrite it afterwards.

UPDATE: Changed syntax of function definition according to the comment given by Stéphane Chazelas, and also renamed my function from test to xtest, because it is a bad idea anyway to name a function 'test'.

Comment: This solution best suited my needs Thankyou!

Comment: Note that it assumes `$variable` is not empty upon first invocation. The `typeset -g` is redundant here and doesn't guard against a `$test_variable` potentially inherited from the environment, it would be better as `unset test_variable; xtest() { ${test_variable=$variable}; echo $test_variable; }`

Comment: The idea to `unset` is is not bad, though a careless programmer could still define it explicitly **after** the function definition. While the `typeset -g` is seemingly redundant, I use it as a habit so that the code works also if `setopt warn_create_global` has been used in the context where the function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the function definition syntax in `zsh` like in the Bourne shell is:

```
funcname() cmd
```

(though it also supports the ksh syntax `function funcname {...}` and a few others).

`fun` is not a `zsh` syntax keyword. With `fun foo() cmd`, you're defining both a `fun` and `foo` function with `cmd` as the body.

I'd also recommend against using `test` as the name of a function as `test` is the name of a standard command (a builtin in `zsh` and most other Bourne-like shells).

Here if you want a function with a *local* variable with a fixed value, you need to embed that value in the definition of the function:

```
mytest() {
  local variable=test
  echo $variable
}
```

`variable` will be local to the function, but still visible to the other functions called by that `mytest` if any. If you'd rather want it be hidden to other functions, that is, do static scoping, you can use `private` (in the `zsh/param/private` module) instead of `local`.

If you want that *fixed value* to be the value of the `$variable` global variable at the time of the definition of `mytest`, you'll still need to embed it in the definition, something like:

```
zmodload zsh/param/private
eval '
  mytest() {
    private variable='${(qq)variable}'
    echo $variable
    otherfunction ...
  }
'
```

Where we embed the content of the variable (properly quoted with `${(qq)...}`) in the definition.

Comment: I edited my post to correct syntax Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : I was also surprised, when I saw this style of function definition, as I had never seen it before, but nevertheless it seems to be valid in Zsh. At least it works in Zsh 5.3.

Comment: @user1934428, but again, `foo bar() cmd` defines 2 functions: `foo` and `bar`, and `fun bar() cmd` defines two functions: `fun` and `bar` (and `'foo bar'() cmd` defines a `"foo bar"` function). Try `fun foo() uname; fun`

Comment: Indeed!!!!!! Lesson learned. I will update my answer accordingly.